# D-link Local wireless

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I created a wireless network inside a D-Link DIR-301 connected to a Mac, What I want is that every device to connect to this network if the browser automatically opens instead of the default homepage, it redirects to my website already set in the localhost of the machine which also has the router attached.
I'd also like to see that instead of the IP to connect to the site, there will be a "fake" link.

What do you advise me? how can I proceed? I state that I am a bit novice in this field, being more a web programmer.

**Edit1:**
I try to be more clear,
I have created through the d-link wireless network where other users through a device such as a smartphone, connect to it without having access to the Internet. but they will have access to the content contained on my computer. so if I connect to this wireless network and I enter the IP address of the router over the html page in a browser, for example 192.168.0.0/index.html (with MAMP opened within the computer) it will display the page. Instead what I would do is create (I think) a custom DNS, so that instead of having to type 192.168.0.0/index.html I'd like to have a link like site.com

Comment: Can your restructure your question a little bit, I don't really understand what you want.

Comment: Basiaclly, you want to connect clients to the wireless network and they get redirected to a webpage hosted on your mac, rather than their homepage?

Comment: yes, I think that's a good solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a captive portal. The problem is that I doubt the DLINK 301 has this function to forward traffic  out of the box. It could have been done with dd-wrt or open-wrt, but neither have are supporting Dlink 301.

Comment: if that's not a problem could you show me a device which is easy to use captive portal service?! since I am willing to buy one, if possibilie I would spend as little as possible

Comment: have a look here: https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=55519

Comment: I was hoping we could get to do the redirect in a somewhat simpler

Comment: Well I doubt there are in the sub 2000 price range, unless you setup a linux router/dhcp server. But it still will some configing.

Comment: if it exists, you could tell me a wireless router or what technical specifications of it to buy one that simplifies things for me, thanks